# get values of aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this controller

```
Posts.listHashtags = ()=>{
    return Post
        .aggregate([{$unwind:"$hashtags"}, 
        {$group:{_id:"$hashtags", count:{$sum:1}}},
        {$sort:{count:-1}},
        {$limit:5},
        {$project: {_id:0, hashtags :"$_id", count:"$count"}}
    ])
        .exec()
}
```

And in my route when i want o access the values it appears undefined, what am i doin wrong?

```
router.get('/posts/hashtags/', verifyAuth, function (req, res) {

  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/posts/hashtags/')
    .then(resposta => {
      console.log('hashtags'+resposta.hashtags)  
    })
    .catch(erro => {
      console.log('Error'+erro) 
    })

});
```

Comment: It's undefined because the results from the aggregate operation will be in an array so `resposta.hashtags` will be undefined, you probably need something like `resposta[0].hashtags`

Comment: @chridam Now it says that cannot read property hashtags of undefined

Comment: Don't you need to call `Posts.listHashtags().then(resposta => console.log(resposta))` inside `router.get('/posts/hashtags/', verifyAuth, function (req, res) { ... }`? Also, what do you get when you do `console.log('reposta', resposta)`?